# Is it possible to install Debian installer to a PC with basically no I/O?

Tags: windows, system-installation, grub, boot-loader

I thought about something interesting.

I have a Celeron 847 2GB DDR3 laptop with UEFI. It's USB ports are broken and due to certain circumstances I can't setup a PXE boot server over Ethernet or connect it's 2.5 HDD to a "donor" PC to install Debian.

So I got a idea to partition a part of the drive using Windows Disk Manager then copying firmware netinstall cd over there only to use GRUBWIN in order to configure bootloader to show the install CD partition so I can boot from that partition.

Literally the only data connection that works in this PC is the AR8161 Ethernet and RTL8188CE WIFI card which I used to download the installation ISO's.

So what do I need to do?

Comment: assuming you can't push a DVD drive onto the motherboard temporarily, can you remove the disk, install to the disk on another machine, then put it back into the original computer?

Comment: @jad well... This is what I used to do in the past but due to certain reasons I can't do it in this laptop this time sadly.

Comment: you should be able to get the disk out and put it in a caddy, for another machine, unless you don't have another machine.  disk partitioning can't be performed on a mounted disk, so unless you can boot to a recovery partition, you won't be able to resize the windows partitioning while you're using it

Comment: @jad good idea.